# How do I add specific CSS classes to each menu anchor?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a menu, *user menu*, with several links. (Let's say *A*, *B*, *C*, and *D*.) I want to add classes/IDs for each snchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.